# Fundamental solution and dissipation result for biharmonic Heat equation

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations

I guess this is easy a very easy question for some people. 
References would be appreciate :

What is the fondamental solution of the biharmonic heat equation ? and how fast is it decreasing in time ?
To look more serious : let $u(t,x)$ be a solution of $$\partial_tu-\Delta^2u=0 \ on \ \ \ \Omega$$  $$u=0 \ \  and\  \  Lu=0\ on \ \ \partial\Omega$$
$$ u(0,\cdot)=u_0$$
 for $\Omega$ an open set of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with smooth boundary, $u_0\in L^2(\Omega)$ and I am interested in the case  where either $L=\partial_{n}$  or $L=\Delta$ for this two cases the problem seems to be well-posed (right ?) and should be exponentially fast dissipate energy. For the heat equation we have something like $|u(t,\cdot)|_{L^2(\Omega)}\leq C\exp{(-at)}$.

Any clue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look for eigenvalues of $\Delta^2$ on your region.  I would try to prove that $\Delta^2$ is strictly positive definite using integration by parts twice.  Then you will get that all the eigenvalues are positive, and hence you will get the exponential decay.

I do remember that some things that work for the heat equation simply don't work at all for the bilaplacian.  For example, you don't have maximal principles.